# How to determine at runtime which version of libc-lock.h used: NPTL or stub?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, shared-libraries, glibc

I have shared library which uses threads. Let's say this is a plugin for main application. I can't change this main application and have access only for my shared library. The main application may be linked with ptreads or may be not linked with pthreads. So, depending on this it will use thread safe version of libc-lock.h or not thread safe.

In glibc

- non-thread safe version is in `bits/libc-lock.h`: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=bits/libc-lock.h;h=7bd935caf4c60058b094dad2aa5d2402fd9df15f;hb=HEAD
- And thread safe is in `sysdeps/nptl/bits/libc-lock.h`: https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/nptl/bits/libc-lock.h;h=d9a82ad962c461f0de8f532fed7013d429ef0f94;hb=HEAD

So, if main application already loaded non-thread safe version of libc-lock.h application will just crash with segfault because my library actively uses threads.

What I want to do is to check at runtime which version if libc-lock.h loaded and if this is not thread safe version just to quit with correct message.

So, is there a way to find this information at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

This is not something I have used but I think you could try "dl_iterate_phdr".

> The `dl_iterate_phdr()` function allows an application to inquire at run
>   time to find out which shared objects it has loaded.

You get access to a `struct dl_phdr_info` which contains a field `dlpi_name` which should be a path of the loaded object.

Comment: This not solves the problem directly. With this function I can only find names of the loaded shared libraries. And since libc-lock is inside libc I will just get /lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6 in all cases. But in my case I found shared library which causes problems. This is libnss_files.so. And if it is loaded I can suggest that this will cause problems. So, thanks anyway.

Comment: @OlegG Interesting. Let me know if you find a cleaner way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Let me build up on cnicutar'a answer. How about you do a quick runtime unittest? Did you know that the dl_iterate_phdr function [does use a mutex internally](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/elf/dl-iteratephdr.c.html#40)? This is very important because [this unwind library depends on the lock behavior](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/libgcc/unwind-dw2-fde-dip.c.html#469). An algorithm could look like this:

thread 1:

- set var breached to false
- spawn thread 2
- wait until thread 2 has entered dl_iterate_phdr
- call dl_iterate_phdr with stub (2)
- set var breached to true

thread 2:

- call dl_iterate_phdr with following code

  ° sleep a reasonably short time (100ms?)

  ° assert that var breached is indeed still false (1)

If glibc is compiled with lock support then the call at (2) will wait till thread 2 has left dl_iterate_phdr. Thus var breached can only be false at (1). But if glibc is not compiled with lock support then (2) does not wait for thread 2 and var breached should be set just-in-time to true before the check at (1) is reached.

Coincidentally, the lock support is enabled in glibc iif the program is compiled with -pthread.

This answer does only work if you have access to the application's dl_iterate_phdr function.